# Translating sysV init script to systemd

Tags: linux, systemd, systemctl

I have init script which works fine.
On a good day It will do all the following;

```
/etc/init.d/my-good-script.sh {start|stop|status|info|check|config|timetravel}
```

Now since `systemd` is the new norm, I want to translate `my-good-script.sh` into a `Systemd Service File`

I found an online example like the following;

```
[Unit]
Description=Postfix Mail Transport Agent
After=syslog.target network.target
Conflicts=sendmail.service exim.service

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/spool/postfix/pid/master.pid
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/network
ExecStartPre=-/usr/libexec/postfix/aliasesdb
ExecStartPre=-/usr/libexec/postfix/chroot-update
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/postfix start
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/postfix reload
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/postfix stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Followed it and was able to do;

```
systemctl {start|stop|status} my-good-script
```

But I am not very sure how to do;

```
systemctl {info|check|config|timetravel} my-good-script
```

Is this even possible or what is the workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, custom service actions are not supported. Instead these should be done as an external script, just a plain old `/usr/bin/my-script-ctl` that accepts the necessary subcommands.

---

If you wrote the daemon/service itself, then certain things, e.g. "current status", can be done using systemd's built-in functions. For example, the `sd_notify()` C function will pass a short line that will be shown in *systemctl status yourservice* (live examples: systemd-timesyncd, systemd-udevd, org.cups.cupsd).

```
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (...)
   Active: active (running) since ...
   Status: "Synchronized to time server 81.29.25.50:123 (2.arch.pool.ntp.org)."
```